# Links not showing in Fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I can't get fancybox to open my links in iframe. My code below. Thanks!

```
<link href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.iframe').fancybox({
'width': '85%', 
'height': '75%',
'transitionIn' : 'none',
'transitionOut' : 'none',
'type' : 'iframe'
}); // end fancybox
}); // end ready
</script>
```

And the link I'm trying to open from my page

```
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2010/07/18/books/review/Boyd-t.html" class="iframe">
<div class="linkcontainer"><h1>Review</h1></div></a>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes from the object properties' names? Remove quotes from the names to the left of the `:`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that. Still no luck. :( On clicking the link a blank iframe window opens briefly and then disappears and the entire page changes to the one in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but the issue has nothing to do with fancybox.

Most probably that page is using `X-Frame-Options response header` to disallow the page to be opened within an `iframe` (the case with fancybox, which uses the html `iframe` tag)

Check this link for further information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Your code will work just fine with any other page from the same domain or not protected against clickJacking though.

Comment: Thanks so much! You are right. That is definitely the issue. I've decided to no longer use iframe for links to external sites. :)