# Load web link to div or iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This may be common problem.I saw several answers for this matter.

1. using jquery load
2. using iframe

I tried both of them and couldn't load easily.
This is for load google.com and it's not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hhh</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#content").attr("src","http://www.google.lk/");
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="content" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to load w3schools.com it loads into the iframe

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hhh</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#content").attr("src","http://w3schools.com/");
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="content" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

When using jQuery load it doesn't work either.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#content").load("src","http://www.google.com/");
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" src="about:blank"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the firebug bar shows this with "`GET http://www.google.com 302 Found 291ms`"

Some body help me to get rid of this.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Chanckjh : forgive the typos, not everybody writes English well

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe

Comment: @JFK yeah but iframe isn't really english

Comment: You are using .load wrong (for the record) ex. **$('#content').load('http://www.google.com/');**

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11286642/1055987 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987

Comment: You can see the reason that you have problem in this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Comment: when use this $('#content').load('google.com'); it shows that "GET http://localhost/seo/google.com 404 Not Found 16ms" in the fire bug bar.

Comment: I need to do get all images of a perticular web page in to my programme.

Comment: I understand the problem with iframe issue.It's really here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery load to display content in a div. There is no `src` for a div.

Affect the `src` for an `iframe` tells your browser to fetch the content and display it in the iframe.

The proper syntax for `load()` would be:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and

```
$("#content").load("page.php");
```

By the way, google.com doesn't like to be loaded from other sites so you're better off using an other example.